# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed - Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

First, I know there are a lot of answers regarding this error, but I can't understand why this is erroring out in my case. I am learning Django and any help would be highly appreciated.

I have a Ticket model with ForeignKey reference to Category, Type & GHDUser as below

models.py
`

```
# from accounts/models.py
class GHDUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    emp_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'),unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)

# from ticket/models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Type(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Type'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Types'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Ticket(models.Model):

    status_options = (
        ('open', 'Open'),
        ('pending', 'Pending'),
        ('closed', 'Closed')
    )

    priority_options = (
        ('high','High'),
        ('medium','Medium'),
        ('low','Low')
    )

    ticket_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=1)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=1)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, blank=True, default='files/Default_Avatar.png')
    raised_by_user = models.ForeignKey(GHDUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='raised_ticket')
```

`

Now, I am able to create an instance for Ticket model from Admin Panel, but when I try to do the same via shell / using data from front end, I am getting the below error.

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

[image: Shell]

Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: As i can see all things are good but first change your FK on_delete.cascade and remove default value. bcz 1 is just a Numerical value not a FK instance. others help ping me hemant.yadav1059@gmail.com

Comment: @HemantYadav, thanks for the comment. I just figured it out. There is another field in my model, support_user which also refers to GHDUser. I had a different default pk, for this field earlier, but then I deleted that pk, but failed to change the same in support_user field. This was causing the issue.